# show a list of files with a certain pattern

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, regular-expression

I have a lot of files named either one of these patterns:

```
1    Surname, Name - Title. Subtitle.extension

2    Surname, N. Surname, N. - Title. Subtitle.extension

3    VV. AA. - Title. Subtitle.extension
```

(the subtitle is optional)

and I need to list only the files with pattern 1, 2 or 3 respectively. Here is an example:

```
....... files in ~/books:
Deleuze, G. Guattari, F. - Mil mesetas.pdf
Sloterdijk, Peter - parque humano.pdf
VV. AA. - Fenomenología de la percepción. Ensayos sobre Merleau-Ponty.pdf
Marx, K. Engels, F. - Capital I.epub
Aristóteles - Metafísica.epub
VV. AA. - Lógica Simbólica.pdf
Zizek, Slavoj - Menos que nada. Hegel y la sombra del materialismo histórico.

....... show filenames with one author:
Sloterdijk, Peter - parque humano.pdf
Aristóteles - Metafísica.epub
Zizek, Slavoj - Menos que nada. Hegel y la sombra del materialismo histórico.


....... show filenames with two authors:
Marx, K. Engels, F. - Capital I.epub
Deleuze, G. Guattari, F. - Mil mesetas.pdf

....... show filenames with "VV. AA.":
VV. AA. - Lógica Simbólica.pdf
VV. AA. - Fenomenología de la percepción. Ensayos sobre Merleau-Ponty.pdf
```

Comment: It might help to show some actual files and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: I hope my example might be clear.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Note that `Aristóteles` doesn't follow the `Surname, Name` template. `Menos que nada` has an empty *extension*

Comment: Do any of the authors have `-` characters in their name?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I notice that, but many pdfs are listened that way too. The main difference is those are not listened as surename1, N. surename2, N. Also, "menos que nada" was a misspell, it was just a random list for example purposes.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Arguably some french authors have that scheme I guess like Merleau-Ponty, also names like Lao-Tse for example.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I have tried ls and wildcards, awk and so, but I think I'm not doing it properly haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob
one-author()   print -rC1 - ~/books/(([^,-]#,)(#c0,1)[^,-]#~'VV. AA.'*)-*(ND:t)
two-authors()  print -rC1 - ~/books/([^,-]#,)(#c2)[^,-]#-*(ND:t)
vv-aa-author() print -rC1 - ~/books/'VV. AA.'*(ND:t)
```

Then:

```
$ one-author
Aristóteles - Metafísica.epub
Sloterdijk, Peter - parque humano.pdf
Zizek, Slavoj - Menos que nada. Hegel y la sombra del materialismo histórico.
$ two-authors
Deleuze, G. Guattari, F. - Mil mesetas.pdf
Marx, K. Engels, F. - Capital I.epub
$ vv-aa-author
VV. AA. - Fenomenología de la percepción. Ensayos sobre Merleau-Ponty.pdf
VV. AA. - Lógica Simbólica.pdf
```

The glob operators above are:

- `#` (equivalent to regex `*`) for 0 or more occurrences of the previous atom
- `(#c<min>,<mac>)` (equivalent to regex `{<min>,<max>}`) for min to max occurrences of the previous atom (note that for `x(#c0,1)` we could also do `(x|)`).
- `pattern1~pattern2`: match pattern1 *and no* pattern2.
- `(...)` is used for grouping.
- `(ND:t)` is a glob qualifier, `N` for `nullglob` (don't fail if there's no matching file), `D` for `dotglob` (include hidden files), `:t` a modifier to only expand to the *tail* (basename) of the file.

Those filter filenames based on the number of `,`s before the first occurrence of `-` (and handling `VV. AA.` specially for one-author ones).

If `"-"` (but not `" - "`) may occur in an author's name, and there's always at least one SPC on both sides of the `-` that delimits the author from the title, you could change it to:

```
set -o extendedglob
one-author()   print -rC1 - ~/books/(([^,]#,)(#c0,1)[^,]#~'VV. AA.'*~*' - '*)' - '*(ND:t)
two-authors()  print -rC1 - ~/books/(([^,]#,)(#c2)[^,]#~*' - '*)' - '*(ND:t)
vv-aa-author() print -rC1 - ~/books/'VV. AA.'*(ND:t)
```

With the `bash` shell, you could do something equivalent with:

```
shopt -s nullglob dotglob extglob
print-tails() {
  (( $# == 0 )) || printf '%s\n' "${@##*/}"
}
one-author() {
  print-tails ~/books/!(!(?(*([^,]),)*([^,]))|'VV. AA.'*|*' - '*)' - '*
}
two-authors() {
  print-tails ~/books/!(!(*([^,]),*([^,]),*([^,]))|*' - '*)' - '*
}
vv-aa-authors() {
  print-tails ~/books/'VV. AA.'*
}
```

With `extglob`, a subset of ksh's extended globs are supported:

- `*(x)` (like zsh's `x#` or regexp `x*`): 0 or more `x`s.
- `?(x)` (like zsh's `(x|)` or `x(#c0,1)` or ERE `x?`): 0 or 1 `x`.
- `!(x)` (like zsh's `^x`): anything that doesn't match `x`.
- within any of those, `|` can be used to signify *or*.

As an equivalent of `zsh`'s `pattern1~pattern2`, we do `!(!(pattern1)|pattern2)`.

Comment: Wow this is a complete explanation! I learned so much!! I'm using zsh right now, so this works perfectly to me. Thank you very much, could you recommend me a textbook/webpage/resource for regex and zsh learning?

Comment: @mao2047, the zsh manual is quite readable (available in `info` / `html` / `pdf` versions; your system will have at least the `man` version, but I wouldn't recommend it for a manual this big; some systems have a `zsh-doc` package for better formats). The [zsh guide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide.html) is quite good as well though a bit dated. For PCRE, see `man pcrepattern`. Or `perldoc perlre` for the (very similar) perl ones. https://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a very good reference and has a few good starting points. Beware there are many flavours of regexps.

Answer (score 1):

bash:

```bsh
declare -a vv one two

for file in *; do 
    authors=${file%% - *}
    case $authors in
        'VV. AA.') vv+=("$file") ;;
        *)  authors=${authors//, /}
            IFS=' ' read -ra names <<<"$authors"
            (( ${#names[@]} == 1 )) && one+=("$file") || two+=("$file")
            ;;
    esac
done

declare -p one two vv
```

outputs

```bsh
declare -a one=([0]="Aristóteles - Metafísica.epub" [1]="Sloterdijk, Peter - parque humano.pdf" [2]="Zizek, Slavoj - Menos que nada. Hegel y la sombra del materialismo histórico.")
declare -a two=([0]="Deleuze, G. Guattari, F. - Mil mesetas.pdf" [1]="Marx, K. Engels, F. - Capital I.epub")
declare -a vv=([0]="VV. AA. - Fenomenología de la percepción. Ensayos sobre Merleau-Ponty.pdf" [1]="VV. AA. - Lógica Simbólica.pdf")
```

If you want an interactive menu:

```bsh
PS3="Select authorship: "
select category in One Two VV quit; do
    case $category in
        One) printf "%s\n" "${one[@]}" ;;
        Two) printf "%s\n" "${two[@]}" ;;
        VV)  printf "%s\n" "${vv[@]}"  ;;
        quit) break ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: I really like the interactive menu idea!